# Mono 3.2 with .NET 4.5 Profile - Not able to find entity framework dll with default installation

Tags: c#, .net, macos, entity-framework, mono

I am using latest version of mono 3.2 that was shipped recently. I am using .NET 4.5 profile but i could not find any references of Entity Framework (when creating class library or mvc3 web application). When i add the EF via NuGet, i see the error System.Data.Entity not being found. FYI i've re-installed MDK 3.2 and Xamarin studio but the error seems to persist.
Does anyone has any clue whats going on? or did anyone was faced the same problem?